What "maintainers version" files need to be manually updated or merged after an Ubuntu Release upgrade other than ".dpkg-dist" and ".ucf-dist" files?
A while ago, I did a release upgrade from Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, to Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS.
During the installation, when the upgrade prompted me with the following questions:
Configuration file '/etc/foo/bar.list'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** defaults.list (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?

I ALWAYS selected "N" to keep my current version of the modified file, to ensure compatibility.
It seems, that after keeping my current version with "N", the Ubunut upgrade also adds the package maintainers version with a different file extension in the same folder as the original (my version) file.
It seems like the NEW Ubuntu Package maintainers version of files are name with the file extensions .dpkg-dist and .ucf-dist.
Now, I would like to merge all of my old files into the new package maintainers version of files, so that I can once again do a distribution upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS without any compatibility issues.
To do this, I need three questions answered:

Are there any files I need to merge/upgrade/update that the Package maintainer saved on my server during upgrade other than ".dpkg-dist" and ".ucf-dist" files?

What exactly are .ucf-dist files, and what old configuration files to they correspond to? For example I know that /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.dpkg-dist is the system maintainers version of /etc/systemd/resolved.conf . But what does a .ucf-dist file correspond to?

Do you have any other tips or suggestions I should be aware of when merging old versions of my configuration files with the package maintainers versions? Any suggestions or tips for completing my release upgrade would be much appreciated!


Thanks

In general, when packages are upgraded/reinstalled/downgraded, all files owned by the package are replaced, except for configuration files ("conffiles"). Conffiles get special treatment as a matter of policy. Conffiles can be provided by packages in two forms:

As regular package contents installed into the correct location directly by dpkg, just like most files.
Generated in maintainer scripts, about which dpkg has no direct idea.

For the former, dpkg can detect when the conffiles have been changed (because it has the hashes for these files), and can ask the user what to do. Depending on how you answer, you get .dpkg-{dist,old} files. However, for the latter, dpkg can't know what the files were supposed to be, since they're generated by scripts. So, instead, the package scripts can use the ucf utility. From the manpage:
This  utility provides a means of asking the user whether or not to accept new versions of
configuration files provided by the package maintainer, with various  heuristics  designed
to  minimize  interaction  time.  It uses debconf to interact with the user, as per Debian
policy.  [...]

This script attempts to provide conffile like handling for files installed under /etc  not
shipped  in  a  Debian package, but handled by the postinst instead.  Debian policy states
that files under /etc which are configuration files must preserve user changes,  and  this
applies to files handled by maintainer scripts as well. Using ucf, one may ship a bunch of
default configuration files somewhere in /usr ( /usr/share/<pkg> is a good location),  and
maintain  files  in  /etc,  preserving  user  changes  and  in  general  offering the same
facilities while upgrading that dpkg normally provides for “conffiles”

And for the .ucf-* files:
During  the  course  of  operations, when working with configuration files, ucf optionally
creates copies of versions of the configuration file in question. For example, a file with
the  suffix  ucf-old holds the old version of a configuration file replaced by ucf.  Also,
copies of the configuration file with the suffixes ucf-new and ucf-dist  may  be  created;
and  the  maintainer scripts should consider purging copies of the configuration file with
these extensions during purge.

If ucf follows the same convention as dpkg, then the .ucf-new files will be new versions of the conffiles temporarily put next to the current version until the next step is determined, and .ucf-dist will be the new versions of the conffiles for which you decided to keep the current version.
